# How to cast md ElementRef to HtmlElement in angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, casting

I have

```
 <input mdInput #try  placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
```

and I get it in ts by

```
 @ViewChild('try') myText : ElementRef;
```

and now I need to get approach to HtmlElement Function
,how I can Cast it?

and I don't want by this way
add  `id="try"` to mdInput 
and get it by :

```
var cel= document.getElementById("try");
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`myText.nativeElement` will contain a reference to the DOM element.  Assert `myText.nativeElement` as `HTMLElement`:

```
let domElement = this.myText.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
```